# How to convert the epoch time to time stamp in talend

Tags: talend, timestamp-with-timezone

For suppose we have 166667777 of file then we want to convert into time stamp how to convert it in talend

Comment: maybe try using this code in a tjava : Date mydate = new Date(Long.parseLong("166667777 ") * 1000);

Answer (score 0):

in a tjava just paste this code  :

```
Date myDate= new Date(Long.parseLong("1081157732") * 1000);
System.out.println(myDate) ; 
SimpleDateFormat jdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String java_date = jdf.format(myDate);
System.out.println(java_date) ;
```

Since you didn't tell us your pattern just see what fits your requirement in the console

Don't forget this import in advanced settings :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat ;
```

Here is the output :

```
[statistics] connected
Mon Apr 05 11:35:32 CEST 2004
2004-04-05 11:35:32
[statistics] disconnected
```

If you are wanting to get the the actual timestamp  here how it is done

- put in the tJava  :

```
long epoch = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(epoch);
LocalDate ld = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(ld);
LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(ldt);
```

And as always don't forget the import :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat ; 
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
```

your output would be :

```
[statistics] connected
1638973017921
2021-12-08
2021-12-08T15:16:57.921
[statistics] disconnected
```